# How to use qDebug() with two parameters in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I am trying to use qDebug() with two parameters but it fails everytime.

When I use separately there is no problem, such as;

```
qDebug() << "img:width = " << img.width();
qDebug() << "img:height = " << img.height();
```

However when I combine them, it gives error.

```
qDebug() << "img:width = " << img.width() << "/t img:height = " << img.height() << std::endl;
```

Error is :

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in '((QDebug*)((QDebug*)((QDebug*)qDebug()().QDebug::operator<<(((const char*)"img:width = ")))->QDebug::operator<<(img.QImage::width()))->QDebug::operator<<(((const char*)"/t img:height = ")))->QDebug::operator<<(img.QImage::height()) << std::endl'
```

Can I use two or more parameters in qDebug?

**Edit::**

Problem still continue for me if I delete `std::endl`

Comment: `std::endl` at the end is not needed.

Comment: I get a compile error if I use std::endl at the end of a qDebug() line.  It compiles and runs fine without it.

Comment: @vahancho if I delete std::endl problem still continue..

Comment: qDebug() << "a: " << a << " b: " << b;  works for me

Comment: you included `<QtDebug>`, didn't you?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove std::endl at the end of the line, std::endl is used with combination with std::cout not with qDebug()

This will work:

```
qDebug() << "img:width = " << img.width() << "/t img:height = " << img.height();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you using `/t` instead of `\t` is the problem (I'm thinking you're trying to place a tab between the two items). Plus yes, std::endl is not needed.

```
qDebug() << "img:width = " << img.width() << "\t" << "img:height = " << img.height();
```

Or

```
qDebug() << "img:width = " << img.width() << "\t img:height = " << img.height();
```

should work.